How to pretend to render any Components of root Layout.js to an specific route in Next.js?
I'm working in Next.js, in my root Layout.js file I added some Components, and they are rendering in my all the routes as I expected.
But I have a route /mobile, where I want want these Components to render. But I have these Components in my root layout.js, so how can I pretend them to render in my /mobile routes?
If you can help than I'll really appreciate for that.
Thanks you, have a nice day.

Can you please clarify you question what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

It's unclear what you're trying to do. What does "pretend" mean in this context? " I added some Components" - added in which way? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

If your problem is that you need to have two different base layouts, you can use route groups:
A route group can be created by wrapping a folder's name in parenthesis: (folderName)
When doing so, you can have two different layouts for routes in the same depth. Example:

(base)
qr

Inside Base there are routes:

about/page.js
contact/page.js

and inside qr there is a page.js
you now have the three pages:
List item

/about
/contact
/qr

With the first two sharing their layout and the third having a different layout. Please refer to the nextjs documentation for extended explanation, as it is an essential part of routing in nextjs
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#convention

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

@Tyler2P: I edited my answer to include your feedback.
